# How to show particular file format from iclouds derive in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, domdocument, icloud, icloud-drive

In my application upload the file from iclouds derive. want to upload  xlsx, docx, txt.

want to upload the xlsx file means from iclouds derive want to display only xlsx another files should not display.[docx,txt]

same if the user want to display docx file means xlsx and txt ,xlsx file should not be display.

Here my code

```
 @IBAction func moveiclouds_BtnClick(_ sender: Any) {
        let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String, "com.microsoft.word.doc", "com.microsoft.excel.xls", kUTTypeCompositeContent as String, kUTTypeJPEG as String], in: .import)
        documentPicker.delegate = self
        self.present(documentPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


extension CreateFeesView: UIDocumentPickerDelegate{
    func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentAt url: URL) {
        let cico = url as URL
        cico_files = cico
        filepath_fees = url.pathExtension
    }
}
```

[image]

from iclouds derive all files are diplaying in recently added list. want to display only particular file in the list. how to achive help me. Thank advance

Comment: kUTTypeXML use this type

Comment: where want to change this type

Comment: let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypePDF as String, "com.microsoft.word.doc", "com.microsoft.excel.xls", kUTTypeCompositeContent as String, kUTTypeJPEG as String], in: .import)
         at this point use only single file format  kUTTypeXMLand check

Comment: let documentPicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: [kUTTypeXML as String, "com.microsoft.excel.xls", kUTTypeXML as String], in: .import)
i done this but not working... help me

Comment: which file format this line show you ?

Comment: i want to show xlsx, doc, txt file three files separately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181791/discussion-between-himanshu-moradiya-and-saravanar).

Comment: ru there? help me

Comment: hello ru there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust the `documentTypes:` argument when creating your document picker.

`documentTypes: ["org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document"]`

will let the user only select docx files.

`documentTypes: ["org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet"]`

will let the user only select xlsx files.